# Date pasting data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem with google sheets.

Normally, everyday I copied data from a spread sheet to  google sheet. But today I copied a cell from google sheet and paste it in another sheet.

After doing this I am unable to paste data from spread sheet to google sheet.

I tried a lot to copy data from Spread sheet and paste on Google sheet but, it paste the date which was copied from google sheet not the date I copied from my spread sheet.

Comment: try CTRL+SHIFT+V

Answer (score 0):

try using the combo:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + V
```